# Swift RealTime Firebase setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key email." Error

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I want to receive the e-mail and other information of the users in the users via real time database, but when I send the request in this way, I get this error.

`

```
Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let user = UserData()
                snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value
                user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
                print(user.email!, user.nameSurname!, user.plusStatus!, user.username!)
            }
            
//            print("User Found")
//            print(snapshot)
        }, withCancel: nil)
```

`

setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key email.' Error This!

Please Help me.

[My DataBase is this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfMrl.png)

```
Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let user = UserData()
                snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value
                user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
                print(user.email!, user.nameSurname!, user.plusStatus!, user.username!)
            }
            
//            print("User Found")
//            print(snapshot)
        }, withCancel: nil)
```

I tried this code but its don't working